# django debug toolbar not showing up for certain views

Tags: django, django-debug-toolbar

debug toolbar doesn't show up for views which return HttpResponse() rather than render_to_response().

a view with `return HttpResponse()`(for test sake) won't show up debug toolbar..

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The problem is not that you are using `HttpResponse`, but the content you return when you do so.

From the [readme](https://github.com/django-debug-toolbar/django-debug-toolbar) on django debug toolbar‘s github page:

> Note: The debug toolbar will only display itself if the mimetype of the response is either `text/html` or `application/xhtml+xml` and contains a closing `</body>` tag.

Comment: +1, it solved my problem last time, I'd like to mention that `<body>` tag has to be part of the rendered template, maybe it'll solve someone's problem in the future

Answer (score 0):

Though this question is marked as answered , but i want to add that ..

Problems/errors with javascript/jQuery in a page, might so much render the debug tool bar not visible for this certain page/view